# Replace all occurrences of "<", ">" inside value attribute

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the requirement to replace all occurrences of "<" and ">" characters that are found inside the value attribute. I want to replace "<" and ">" characters with ""

This is my sample html:

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" value="<first set><second set><third set>" />
<input type="text" value="<fourth set><fifth set><sixth set>" />
</form>
```

I tried using javascript replace method but no luck.

Comment: `str.replace('<', '').replace('>', '')`?

Comment: Above solution will replace "<" and ">" from tags as well. I want to replace these characters only from value attribute

Comment: You have given no context of the problem. Is this html on the page, or just a string variable in javascript? Can you [edit] the question to show what you have tried so far, even if it is wrong, so we have a starting point to help you from?

Comment: Can you please update your question. Its not clear.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Show us the code you tried using the JavaScript `replace` method that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this pure JavaScript function:

```js
function removeLessGreaterThan(html) {
    // Use the DOM API to change the value attribute values:
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = html;
    var inputs = span.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('value', inputs[i].value.replace(/[<>]/g, ''));
    }
    return span.innerHTML;
}

// Sample data:
var html = '<form name="form1"> <input type="text" value="Here is a >test<." /> <input type="text" value="And another >test<." /> </form>';
html = removeLessGreaterThan(html);
console.log(html);
```

Comment: OK, IE does not support the ECMA2015 standard `Array.from()`. I have updated the code to work in IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
const FORM_NAME = "form1";

var fields = document.getElementsByName(FORM_NAME)[0].getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].value = fields[i].value.replace(/[<>]/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting this way. Please go through the code.

```js
function ReplaceMyValues()
  {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
   if(inputs[i].type=="text")
   {
    var currentValue=inputs[i].value.replace(/[<>]/g, "");
    inputs[i].value = currentValue;
   }

   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1"> <input type="text" value="<first set><second set><third set>" /> <input type="text" value="<fourth set><fifth set><sixth set>" /> 
<input id="Test" type="button" value="Replace" onclick="ReplaceMyValues();"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Throws script error. I am using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Your solution works fine. Just curious, can't we do it using simple javascript(without jquery).

Comment: @Shrinath, I've updated the code with javascript format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$(".yourInput").val($(".yourInput").val().replace('<', '').replace('>', ''))
```